# Linux/Bash: Sourcing a script and then assigning it to a variable

Tags: python, linux, bash

I saw this in the instructions for a Python templating language (specifically, the tutorial for Genshi):

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. python geddit/controller.py geddit.db
```

I understand what it means to source a script, but I don't understand the reason behind assigning the sourced script to a variable, here, "PYTHONPATH".

Running `. python` doesn't work, but `PYTHONPATH=. python` does.
But so does `test=. python`, so I know what's in my `PYTHONPATH` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash lets you assign environment variables for one call only.

```
$ VAR1=one VAR2=two someprogram param1 param2
```

sets VAR1 and VAR2 before running someprogram. Your command

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. python geddit/controller.py geddit.db
```

sets PYTHONPATH to the current directory so that .py files in the current directory can be imported then runs "python geddit/controller.py geddit.db"

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is not what you are thinking. :) The command does not assign the sourced file or even source a file. In bash, you can do something like this:

```
ENVIRONMENT_VAR=VALUE command
```

This will set an environment variable to a value and then execute command with the modified environment. After the call the environment var will have it's old value again.

So the line above just sets the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to `.` - the current directory - and executes the command `python geddit/controller.py geddit.db`